# MySql select rows of unique values between two columns

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to get this to work.

I have this table:

```
A  B
- - -
1  2
1  3
1  4
4  1
3  1
2  1
```

I just want the first three rows,

```
A  B
- - -
1  2
1  3
1  4
```

Because the last 3 rows are merely the opposite of the first three.

How can I do this with a MySQL Query?

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a06758/1)

Given this schema,

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`A` int, `B` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`A`, `B`)
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (1, 4),
    (4, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (2, 1)
;
```

You can use this query to take your a,b data, reduce it, and eliminate the duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(A,B) AS A,
                GREATEST(A,B) AS B
  FROM t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a06758/1/0)**:

```
| A | B |
|---|---|
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
```